# Access .plist Values

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I am building an app that has a pickerview, thus, I had created a .plist file to make the keys and values. The only issue is I want to be able to access the .plist values. The thing is, the values are name strings which when selected on the picker view i would like to create an if statement where i call a mobile number. I need guide on access the values if that is possible

Any idea on how to carry this out?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:  // here data is file nale of plist
                    @"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    // Build the dictionary from the plist  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```